# Regular expression in java( pattern to match a part of a string)

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

Could any one please help me write a regular expression to match a part of the string given below.

"Cecscec\n:90A:/5645644343\nvalue1\nvalue2\nvalue3\n:80F:/245343\nfglfejfj\n"

I want to extract only value 1 and value 2 from the above string which is present in :90A:/ which can be considered for look behind.

Output:

> Value2
> Value3

Pattern:
((?<=(:90A:/).{0,40}[\n].{0,40}[\n]).asterisk)[^:]asterisk

I am struggling since so many days. I would be very grateful if someone could help me on this.

Thanks

Comment: The `\n`s in your sample are line-breaks?

Comment: Yes Kevin, I am trying to skip the value 1 and value 2. Making a small change in the question. I want to find value 2 and value 3

Comment: The pattern [works in Java](https://ideone.com/fhdyxq) also see https://regex101.com/r/ksN3Wh/1/

Answer (score 0):

Alternative regex:

```
":90A:/(?:[^\n]{0,40}\n){2}([^\n]+)\n([^\n]+)"
```

Regex in context:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "Cecscec\n:90A:/5645644343\nvalue1\nvalue2\nvalue3\n:80F:/245343\nfglfejfj\n";

    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(":90A:/(?:[^\n]{0,40}\n){2}([^\n]+)\n([^\n]+)").matcher(input);
    if(matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println("Group1: '" + matcher.group(1) + "'");
        System.out.println("Group2: '" + matcher.group(2) + "'");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Group1: 'value2'
Group2: 'value3'
```